# How do I fix this dropzone.js layout issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropzone.js

I am working on a project and started using dropzone.js, and then was moved to another task, and when I returned to this task, a former co-worker had made some modifications..

Its prob an easy issue, but I am needing to learn -  he created some TABLES which I dont want, I just want to be able to display the VAR data on items I create and control via css.

My issue, is I am lost on how to use his functions in the  and make them be more "html" based so I can assign my css to it.

I´m trying dropzone.js and want the layout like on this page dropzonejs.com or this Work with DropzoneJS

```html
    <script>
var files = [];
var total_count = 0;
var processing = false;
function deleteFile(fileid) {
 var file = files[fileid];
 total_count -= file.count;
 files[fileid] = null;
 document.getElementById('dr_total').innerHTML = total_count;
 var row = document.getElementById('dr_'+fileid);
 row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
 dz_deleteRemoteFile(file.file);
}
function checkout() {
 if (processing) {
  return true; 
 }
 
 if (files.length < 1) {
  alert('Please upload files');
  return false; 
 }
 processing = true;
 document.getElementById('btnCheckout').innerHTML = 'Processing...';
 var result = dz_addOrder();
 if (!result) {
  document.getElementById('btnCheckout').innerHTML = 'Checkout';
  processing = false; 
 }
}
</script>

<script language="javascript" src="dropzone.js"></script>
<script>
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  maxFilesize: 200, // MB
  //acceptedFiles: "application/csv,text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel",
  clickabke: false,
  dictDefaultMessage: 'Drag or Select files to Upload',
  method: "POST",
  uploadMultiple: false,
  accept: function(file, done) {
   if (file.name.substring(file.name.length-3).toLowerCase() != 'csv') {
    done('ERROR: Invalid file type, only CSV files allowed.');
   } else {
    done();
   }
  },
  error: function(file, errorMessage, xhr) {
    alert('ERROR: '+file.name+' '+errorMessage);
  },
  success: function(file, message) {
  var ret = JSON.parse(message);
  if (ret.status == "ERROR") {
   alert('ERROR: '+file.name+' '+ret.message);
   return false; 
  }
  var obj = {
   file:ret.file,
   name:file.name,
   count:ret.count
  };
  files.push(obj);
  total_count += ret.count;
  var table = document.getElementById('dr_files');
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  row.id = 'dr_'+(files.length-1);
  row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = file.name;
  row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = ret.count;
  row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = '<button class="verifybuttonred" onclick="deleteFile('+(files.length-1)+')">delete</button>';
  
  document.getElementById('dr_total').innerHTML = total_count;
  
  var dz = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
   dz.removeFile(file);
  },1000,dz);
  }
};
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="basic.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dropzone.css">

<body>
<form action="data_hygiene/upload.php" id="myDropzone" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="clientid" id="clientid" value="0">
</form>
<div id="dr_filelist">
<br/><br/><br/><table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" bordercolor="#000000" width="100%" id="dr_files">
 <tr><th width="70%">File</th><th width="15%">Count</th><th width="15%">Options</th></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" bordercolor="#000000" width="100%" id="dr_files">
 <tr><th width="70%">Total</th><th width="15%"><div id="dr_total"></div></th><th width="15%"><button class="buttongreen" id="btnCheckout" onClick="checkout();">Checkout</button></th></tr>
</table>
```

So you will in near the end, he has the :

```html
  var table = document.getElementById('dr_files');
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  row.id = 'dr_'+(files.length-1);
  row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = file.name;
  row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = ret.count;
  row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = '<button class="verifybuttonred" onclick="deleteFile('+(files.length-1)+')">delete</button>';
```

this is what I am wanting to remove from a TABLE layout...

This is how it currently looks - (which is crap)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9BQG.png)